# Perimeter search with a maximum of 1 item of a specific group

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I have a table of shops with some chains among them. When I do a proximity search, I want only the closest shop of each chain to be included in the result. However, I want all shops from the non-chains to be found.

My idea is to assign a group to the chain shops and then filter them in the SQL - but how?

| shop_id | shop | shop_lat | shop_lon | chaingroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SHOP1 | 55.8 | 9.4 | NULL |
| 2 | SHOP2 | 55.9 | 9.5 | 2 |
| 3 | SHOP3 | 55.1 | 9.6 | NULL |
| 4 | SHOP4 | 55.2 | 9.7 | 3 |
| 5 | SHOP5 | 55.3 | 9.8 | NULL |
| 6 | SHOP6 | 55.4 | 9.9 | 2 |
| 7 | SHOP7 | 55.5 | 10.0 | NULL |
| 8 | SHOP8 | 55.6 | 10.1 | 5 |
| 9 | SHOP9 | 55.7 | 10.2 | NULL |
| 10 | SHOP10 | 55.8 | 10.3 | 5 |

My SQL:

```
SELECT shop, ((ACOS(SIN(53.58393 * PI() / 180) * SIN(shop_lat * PI() / 180) + COS(53.58393 * PI() / 180) * COS(shop_lat * PI() / 180) * COS((10.01413 - shop_lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.150779448 * 1.609344) as distance, chaingroup
FROM shops
GROUP BY shop_id
HAVING distance <= 10 
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

Result should be:

| shop | distance | chaingroup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SHOP1 | 1.0 | NULL |
| SHOP2 | 2.0 | 2 |
| SHOP3 | 3.0 | NULL |
| SHOP4 | 4.0 | 3 |
| SHOP5 | 5.0 | NULL |
| SHOP7 | 7.0 | NULL |
| SHOP8 | 8.0 | 5 |
| SHOP9 | 9.0 | NULL |

As you can see, SHOP10 is not listed because SHOP8 from chain no. 5 has already been found.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a valid simple data,`shop_id`, `shop_lat` & `shop_lon` data are missing

Comment: @SelVazi - Thanks for your comment - I have made the appropriate changes on the data table